# mysql error on xampp 1.7.7 for windows

Tags: windows, mysql, xampp, cakephp

All of a sudden my XAMPP installation is playing silly buggers when I try to Cake bake.

I get a recurring error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 6 Error on delete of 'C:\xampp\tmp\#sql...MYD' (Errcode: 13)
```

Where the file name changes between attempts.  I have tried reinstalling Xampp to no avail.  I have also tried baking projects that were completed and are known to work but stil get the error (so I do not think it is my database schema).

The error also popped up in phpmyadmin once but I cannot replicate it.  It only happens all the time when I try baking with CakePHP 2.1.3-18

Comment: Looks like file permission error. It's possible it only happens when temporary table is used.

Comment: That makes sense... but it is running on Windows.  Any idea how to correct the permissions?

Comment: Contrary to popular belief Windows does have some access control ;-) and it could be causing this.
Check what user is running mysqld process and if that user has permissions to access \xampp\tmp  if you find the problem there either change mysql tmpdir to somewhere it can access or change \xampp\tmp permissions